# Create a ZIP in PHP: does class ZipArchive exist on Bluemix?

Tags: php, download, zip, ibm-cloud, php-ziparchive

I’m developing a simple PHP application and I need to download multiple files with a single request, which in this case occurs by clicking a button. I’ve seen several web resources that say the way to do this is to create a zip file that contains the files I want to download. The first two instructions to do this are:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open(“zipname.zip”, ZipArchive::CREATE);
```

But during the execution the first instruction doesn’t work. In the log window, the error that appears is this:

```
Class 'ZipArchive' not found in /home/vcap/app/htdocs/download.php
```

I’ve echoed `phpinfo()` to see if `ZipArchive` is enabled on Bluemix, but it wasn't found.

If it's possible to do this, then how can I make it work?

Otherwise, is there another way to download multiple files that works on Bluemix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the PHP module `zip` to the `options.json` file.

If you don't have the options.json file yet, you can create it under the `.bp-config` directory in your application root directory.

The `options.json` file should have the following format:

```
{
    "PHP_EXTENSIONS": [ "zip", "zlib", "pdo" ]
}
```

After creating this file push your application again using `cf push`.

Comment: Thank you! I've created the folder and the file (in which the string " $ more .bp-config/options.json " out of the parenthesis generates error and it's not correct, I've not written it, right?), but it doesn't work. if I write "zip" or another extension like "zlib" or "pdo", the content of the page is not loaded. Instead if I write, for example, "curl", it works without problems... Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Sorry I was not clear, you don't need to add "$more ..." in the file. I updated answer with right file format.

Comment: It works! Before I included only "zip", but since the declaration of php_extensions overwrites the default one, I needed to include also "curl" to let all the project work. Thank you!

Comment: I am glad it is working now. Would you mind accepting my answer then?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like BlueMix didn't add it to their server, so you can't use it.

Maybe this is an alternative for you: https://github.com/Grandt/PHPZip

Comment: I'll take a look. Thank you!